# Why is tkinter "Fail to allocate bitmap" crashing the Spyder kernel after script completes?

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter

I have written a short script which emulates a "waterfall" display, wherein a very long image is displayed by scrolling it through a smaller window. My program scrolls two images side-by-side: the first image is uncalibrated, and the second image is a calibrated version of the first image. In practice, these images are generated line-by-line, and would be displayed in (roughly) real time. My emulator is not real time, but just reads in the two images from data files.

Here is a screen capture of the GUI:
[image: Screen capture of GUI running]

I am new to tkinter, and just trying to follow tutorials online to make a simple GUI. The GUI windows are each 300x480 - the two images are ~10000x480 color images with are scrolled through the GUI windows simultaneously.

The script basically runs as expected until the end.

After the two images have completed scrolling, in Spyder the kernel dies and is restarted. No error is given other than "Kernel died, restarting". Running my program from the command line, I get the error "Fail to allocate bitmap" after the script has displayed the full images. I presume the "Fail to allocate bitmap" is what is causing the kernel to die in Spyder, and that it is something I am doing wrong with Tk.

Here is my (pseudo)code:

```
import tkinter 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
import numpy as np
import sys

lines = <length of image along one dimension>
extractedImageArray = <uncalibrated 24-bit image as array of dimension [lines, 480, 3]>
calibratedImageArray = <calibrated 24-bit image as array of dimension [lines, 480, 3]>

im1 = np.zeros((300,480,3), dtype=np.uint8)
im2 = np.zeros((300,480,3), dtype=np.uint8)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('960x350+0+0')
root.title('Waterfall Emulator')
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=0)

root.button = tkinter.Button(root,text='Quit',command=root.destroy)
root.button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
for i in range(lines):
    try:
        im1 = np.vstack((im1[1:,:,:],extractedImageArray[i,:,:].reshape((1,480,3))))
        leftImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(im1))
        leftImageLabel = tkinter.Label(image=leftImage)
        leftImageLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        # Store a reference to a PhotoImage object, to avoid it
        # being garbage collected! This is necesary to display the image!
        leftImageLabel.image = leftImage

        im2 = np.vstack((im2[1:,:,:],calibratedImageArray[i,:,:].reshape((1,480,3))))        
        rightImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(im2))
        rightImageLabel = tkinter.Label(image=rightImage)
        rightImageLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        # Store a reference to a PhotoImage object, to avoid it
        # being garbage collected! This is necesary to display the image!
        rightImageLabel.image = rightImage
        
        root.update()
    except:
        sys.exit()
        
root.mainloop()
```

The program basically does what I need it to, but it's irritating that the kernel dies at the end instead of there being a clean exit. I think the error must be due to my inexperience with tkinter.

Why is the kernel dying after the script is executed?

=======================================================

ADDED:

For completeness, here is how I modified my script after Martineau's solution: I pulled the button creation outside the loop and now just update the labels.

```
<--snip-->

root.button = tkinter.Button(root,text='Quit',command=root.destroy)
root.button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

leftImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(im1))
leftImageLabel = tkinter.Label(image=leftImage)
leftImageLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

rightImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(im2))
rightImageLabel = tkinter.Label(image=rightImage)
rightImageLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        
for i in range(lines):
    try:
        im1 = np.vstack((im1[1:,:,:],extractedImageArray[i,:,:].reshape((1,480,3))))
        leftImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(im1))
        leftImageLabel.configure(image=leftImage)
        # Store a reference to a PhotoImage object, to avoid it
        # being garbage collected! This is necesary to display the image!
        leftImageLabel.image = leftImage

        im2 = np.vstack((im2[1:,:,:],calibratedImageArray[i,:,:].reshape((1,480,3))))        
        rightImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(im2))
        rightImageLabel.configure(image=rightImage)
        # Store a reference to a PhotoImage object, to avoid it
        # being garbage collected! This is necesary to display the image!
        rightImageLabel.image = rightImage
```

Comment: My image wasn't actually completely printing - your solution works perfectly. @martineau can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating ~10000 `Label` widgets, each with an associated image — which takes a lot of memory.

You really don't need all of them at once since your program only "scrolls" in one direction — which means you should be able to significantly reduce the amount of memory required by *changing* the images associated with a fixed, relatively small, number of `Label`s.

You can change existing `Label` widgets by using their [`config()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method.